# python-ggplot in IPython cutting off legend in figures

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook, python-ggplot

I am plotting using python-ggplot, which I know is still in development. However rather frustratingly in Ipython notebooks when try to plot part of the legends are being cut off. I also tried in the %qtconsole and got the same chopped image, so I think its being delivered chopped. How can I increase the canavas size or whatever I need to do?

```
print inf_df[:10]

ggplot(aes(x='val', colour='lang', fill=True, alpha = 0.3), data=inf_df) + geom_density() + labs("Score", "Frequency") + \
scale_x_continuous(limits=(0,0.01)) + ggtitle('\n Swahili - blue, French - yellow, English - black')

      qid lang         metric       val
1   Q1410   fr  referencerate  0.000453
6   Q1410   en  referencerate  0.002962
11  Q1410   sw  referencerate  0.000000
16   Q805   fr  referencerate  0.001971
21   Q805   en  referencerate  0.005639
26   Q805   sw  referencerate  0.000000
31   Q804   fr  referencerate  0.001217
36   Q804   en  referencerate  0.001908
41   Q804   sw  referencerate  0.000000
46  Q3769   fr  referencerate  0.001159
```

[image: chopped legend]

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, this is fixed if you install latest development version of matplolib (issue with tight layout). You can try to play with the value of the `InlineBackend.rc` config (use `%config` magic) that may help you deactivate tight layout.

Comment: When I call `print p.draw().get_tight_layout()` I receive False. So I think that means that tight_layout is not being used.

Comment: If I use a long ggtitle the Canvas stretches to be large enough, so this is my janky work-around for now. `ggtitle(ametric + '\n\n [lots of spaces go here]')`

Comment: The `tight_layout` will be triggerd by the display hook of the inline backend, so you probably cannot programtically detect it has been used. See `core/pylabtools.py:112` try to remove `bbox_inches='tight'` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: This was the problem: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/33. The problem is fixed in the latest released version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move it manually with   `+ theme(subplots_adjust={'right': 0.75})`

```
ggplot(aes(x='val', colour='lang', fill=True, alpha = 0.3), data=inf_df) + geom_density() + labs("Score", "Frequency") + \
    scale_x_continuous(limits=(0,0.01)) + ggtitle('\n Swahili - blue, French - yellow, English - black') + 
 theme(subplots_adjust={'right': 0.75})
```